# 'before must be a child of the NavigationPage (Parameter 'before')' in Xamarin/.net Maui

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I was creating a demo app in .Net Maui & wanted to insert a page before navigation by using **InsertPageBefore** method of Navigation.

Referred from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage)

I am at **MainPage** & navigation to **Page4** but before navigation to **Page4** I want to insert **Page3** to make my navigation stack looks like below

*MainPage/Page3/Page4*

This is the code for navigation to **Page4**

```
private void Page4ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Page3(),new Page4());
}
```

My App.cs code

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

The error message I am getting is **'before must be a child of the NavigationPage (Parameter 'before')'**

Comment: You need to use the existing reference to Page4 that has already been added to the stack

Comment: So do I have to create Page4 object before passing it in InsertPageBefore? @Jason

Comment: You should do this after you’ve already navigated to Page4

Comment: In which file/class is the Page4ButtonClicked event handler defined?

Comment: It's defined in MainPage @ewerspej

Comment: Thanks, I solved my issue because of you guys. I had to call **InsertPageBefore** in my Page4 OnAppearing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Json & @ewerspej comments.

I was calling **Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Page3(),new Page4());** from MainPage.

which should have been called after navigating to **Page4**.

So if you want to add a page in the navigation stack after navigation.

Call the **Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Page3(),this);** method like this.

Posting this as an answer for others who is still stuck in this issue.